# Как раздавать интернет, если стоит Linux? (две сетевухи)

Tags: сервер, linux

У меня есть машина, на которой есть две сетевухи и стоит на ней Linux Debian.
Как можно через вторую сетевуху раздавать интернет другому компьютеру?
Нужно ли что-либо настраивать в Linux или она сама начнет раздавать интернет?

Answer (score 6):

1.Нужно включить форвардинг пакетов:

-Открываем /etc/sysctl.conf

-Вписываем/дописываем net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

-Сохраняем

2.Настроить НАТ (полагаю, что у вас уже установлен iptables)

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.2 -j MASQUERADE
>
> Где 192.168.0.2 - айпи (можно сеть/диапазон подставить) того компьютера(ов), которые должны иметь доступ в интернет.

P.S. Подобные вопросы задаются на [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/)

> РутКод - для системных администраторов и специалистов поддержки ("Как настраивать?");

Comment: и все что ли? больше ничего делать не нужно?

Comment: Зависит от ответов на другие вопросы, типа "есть инет на linux-боксе", "надо ли устанавливать соединение с инет-провайдером по требованию" и т.п.

Comment: выполнил все по пунктам, 2-ой пункт выдал ошибку
> iptables v1.4.8: Cannot use -E with -A
> Try `iptables -h` or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Comment: А там есть ещё и другие ключики, в т.ч. -L -- list и -D -- delete. Ну и ещё несколько

Comment: так а почему ошибка с -A?
-E нужно указывать?

Comment: Наоборот, одновременное их присутствие недопустимо. Если хотите, покажите здесь вывод `iptables -L`, возможно, тогда реакция станет понятней. Я с ней почти дела не имел, но подозреваю, что Вы пытаетесь это правило загнать ещё раз.

Answer (score 0):

Друг, не парьтесь. Раз вы не знаете, что такое маскарадинг пакетов, возьмите любую не заумную фронт-энд систему. Сейчас и бесплатные есть. Например fantomas.

Ну, а с натом лучше использовать в данном случае не -s подсетка, а -d eth0, например. Опишите подробнее, какая карта и куда смотрит, я вам готовый конфиг скину.

---

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

# Чистим все текущие политики..
iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X && ipt

#Политики по умолчанию
iptables -t filter -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Себе, любимому разрешаем все и всегда.
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT.

#Объясняем, что делать с запросами извне..
iptables -A INPUT ! -i eth1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT.

# Маскарадим..
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE.

#Ну и если вдруг захочется зырить, кто куда ходит
#делаем позрачный прокси
#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

Comment: eth0 - карта к которой подключен компьютер.
192.168.0.1 -сервер, 192.168.0.2 -компьютер.
eth1 - карта к которой подключен интернет.

Comment: Это как `-d eth0`?

>iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

Тоже интересное правило: и на входе eth1, и на выходе?
По поводу loopback - а нафига? Сперва разрешать все политиками, а затем еще и правилом добивать? Аналогичная фигня с запросами извне, у вас уже все разрешено, ваши запросы извне будут всегда в нуле.

`-s` указываю, когда нужно выбрать определенные компьютеры из некоторого диапазона, на всякий случай. Что касается `-o eth1`, он не нужен ибо в построутинге будет только то, что и так направлено на eth1 на этапе выбора интерфейса по dst-ip