# Раздача интернета: как открыть порты?

Tags: сервер, linux

Здравствуйте! Ребят, я как то раз задавал вопрос на ХэшКод. Вот ссылка на него - [Как раздавать интернет, если стоит Linux? (две сетевухи)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22105/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4), который предоставил пользователь @skykub мне очень помог. С тех пор никаких проблем, за что ему конечно большое спасибо. Но я не выполнял последнюю закомментированную строчку "делаем позрачный прокси". Т.к. не понимаю, что она значит. Сейчас появилась необходимость не только предоставить доступ для компьютера eth0 - 192.168.0.2, но и открыть порты, чтобы можно было с компьютера запускать сервера, доступные в сети интернет.Какое правило нужно дописать, чтобы был переброс портов? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял:

Допустим у вас на  хосте 192.168.0.2, есть какой то сервис, допустим web, порт 80. И вы хотите что бы из интернета можно было попасть на этот сервис.Тогда:

```
iptables -t nat  -I PREROUTING -d <ваш внешний ip> -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
```

В принципе все, если предыдущие правила остались не измененными, все должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую, отпишусь. Правила ведь сохраняются?

Comment: Это у вас надо спросить)

Comment: Я просто не помню, прописывал ли что-то для сохранения правил :)Кстати, вот у Вас написано на порт 80, возможно ли сделать на все порты?

Comment: Сохранятся все. Вам врятли все порты то нужны, вам никто не мешает такое же правило но с другим портом прописать. Но "возможно ли сделать на все порты" вы просто еще не разобрались с поставленной задачей.

Comment: Я для тестов программы запускаю, так же при разработке, использую различные порты. Мне не очень удобно будет каждый раз новое правило добавлять.

Comment: емнип, если порт не указывать, то поумолчанию все порты будут...

Comment: Выполнил следующую команду:iptables -t nat  -I PREROUTING -d <ip выданный провайдером> -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5300 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2К сожалению не сработало, порт как был не доступен, так и остался.

Comment: А нет, извиняюсь, работает, я просто запускал сервис на udp протоколе. Простая смена tcp на udp в строчке не помогает, можете подсказать как будет правильней?

Comment: Должно работать, iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d <ip выданный провайдером> -m udp -p udp --dport 5300 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2