# Шлюз + dhcp + роутер CENTOS 7 (linux)

Tags: linux, centos, dhcp, шлюз

Всем привет. Изначально все работало по такой структуре. Кабель Beeline -> Роутер -> порт на сервер + порт на домашний комп + wifi.

Но после отвала роутера от ддоса, было решено изменить структуру сервера следующим образом:
Кабель Beeline -> сервер - > Роутер - > wifi + порт на домашний комп

Тем самым сервер CENTOS 7 (последний) стоит как основной, у него стоит апач, и открыто штук 10-15 нужных портов, активен firewalld и selinux. И воткнуто в него два интерфейса гигабитных, один в который воткнут кабель билайна (внешний enp3s0) другой соответственно внутренний уходящий в роутер enp2s0

Далее я попытался пользоваться разными статьями, в надежде подключить интернет на ветке роутер - домашний комп:

> https://oss-it.ru/129
>
> [Как раздавать интернет, если стоит Linux? (две сетевухи)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22105/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-linux-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8)
>
> https://bozza.ru/art-259.html

И в итоге единственное что у меня получилось, это Связь кабель - сервер - домашний комп(без роутера изначально решил чтобы не нагружать свой мозг).
Пинговался сервер, пинговался любой ИП интернетный, но на сайты не заходило, даже если вводить айпишник, при этом пинг проходил. Тогда я подумал - окей, надо вставлять роутер, чтобы дальше уже думать с ним. Но при вставке роутера, роутер говорит что он подключился но в итоге не пингует уже ни он, ни я. Кароче я встал втупик полный и прошу помощи.
ВАЖНО: На сервере точно есть интернет.
ВАЖНО2: Роутер и домашний комп отказываются соединяться с сервером, если оставить параметры получения айпшника и остального -Автоматически, хотя на сервере стоит dhcp(поидеи)
ВАЖНО3: Фаерволл отключаю при попытках дабы не нагонять лишних проблем.
Помогите пожалуйста =\

> MTU = 1500 DNS = 8.8.8.8

Comment: /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1                   
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил свой же вопрос. IPtables содержал дополнительные настройки (которые я делал изза DDOS, которые препятствовали выходу в интернет). Вопрос решен сбросом настроек iptables и настройкой заново по этой статье https://oss-it.ru/129